# How to solve bad state: element error in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I am relatively new to using Flutter and Android Studio and recently while trying to build an app, I came across this error. I tried some solutions online but it doesn't seem to work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This was the error that was received. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaYMY.png)

I have also attached the app dart file and the positioning system dart file.

myapp.dart

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_finder/routing.dart';
import 'package:path_finder/routingWidget.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'location.dart';
import 'locationWidget.dart';
import 'map_widget.dart';
import 'mock_positioning_system.dart';
import 'positioning_system.dart';
import 'user_position.dart';
import 'user_position_widget.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final PositioningSystem positioningSystem;
  final UserPosition userPosition;
  final Routing routing;

  const MyApp(this.positioningSystem, this.userPosition, this.routing, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<MapWidget> _mapWidgets = [
    const MapWidget(imagePath: 'assets/E02.png'),
    const MapWidget(imagePath: 'assets/E03.png'),
    const MapWidget(imagePath: 'assets/E04.png'),
  ];
  int _currentFloor = 0;
  bool _isLocationSearchVisible = false;
  Location? _selectedLocation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.positioningSystem.start();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.positioningSystem.stop();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateSelectedLocation(Location location) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedLocation = location;
      _isLocationSearchVisible = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: widget.userPosition),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: widget.positioningSystem),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            width: 400,
            height: 565,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                // MapWidget here
                _mapWidgets[_currentFloor],
                if (_selectedLocation != null &&
                _selectedLocation!.z / 100 - 1 == _currentFloor)
                // UserPositionWidget here
                const UserPositionWidget(),
                Visibility(
                  visible: _isLocationSearchVisible,
                  child: LocationSearch(
                      widget.routing,
                      _updateSelectedLocation
                  ),
                ),
                if (_selectedLocation != null &&
                    !_isLocationSearchVisible &&
                _selectedLocation!.z / 100 - 1 == _currentFloor)
                Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.2,
                  child: RoutingWidget(
                    routing: widget.routing,
                    path: widget.routing.getShortestPath(_selectedLocation!),
                    destinationName: _selectedLocation!.name,
                  ),
                ),
                // DropdownButton here
                if (!_isLocationSearchVisible)
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 20,
                  child: DropdownButton<int>(
                    value: _currentFloor,
                    items: const [
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 0,
                        child: Text('Floor 2'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 1,
                        child: Text('Floor 3'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 2,
                        child: Text('Floor 4'),
                      ),
                    ],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentFloor = value!;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _isLocationSearchVisible = !_isLocationSearchVisible;
              });
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

positioning_system.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart';
import 'anchor.dart';
import 'ble_manager.dart';
import 'distance_computation.dart';
import 'trilateration.dart';
import 'user_position.dart';

import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

class PositioningSystem extends ChangeNotifier {
  final BLEManager _bleManager = BLEManager();
  late final List<AnchorDistance> _anchorDistances = [
    AnchorDistance(id: 'anchor1_1', x: 0, y: 0, z: 100, distance: 0),
    AnchorDistance(id: 'anchor1_2', x: 0, y: 100, z: 100, distance: 0),
    AnchorDistance(id: 'anchor1_3', x: 200, y: 300, z: 100, distance: 0),
    AnchorDistance(id: 'anchor2_1', x: 0, y: 0, z: 200, distance: 0),
    AnchorDistance(id: 'anchor2_2', x: 0, y: 100, z: 200, distance: 0),
    AnchorDistance(id: 'anchor2_3', x: 200, y: 300, z: 200, distance: 0),
    AnchorDistance(id: 'anchor3_1', x: 0, y: 0, z: 300, distance: 0),
    AnchorDistance(id: 'anchor3_2', x: 0, y: 100, z: 300, distance: 0),
    AnchorDistance(id: 'anchor3_3', x: 200, y: 300, z: 300, distance: 0),
  ];
  String _beaconId = 'beacon_id';
  final UserPosition _userPosition;

  PositioningSystem(this._userPosition);

  Future<String> getDeviceId() async {
    String androidId = '';
    final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        androidId = await deviceInfo.androidInfo.then((value) => value.androidId);
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Error getting device ID: $e');
    }
    return androidId;
  }

  void start() {
    print('Start Scanning...');

    getDeviceId().then((value) {
      _beaconId = value;
      print('beacon id: $_beaconId');
    });

    _bleManager.startScan();
    _bleManager.scanResults.listen(_handleScanResults);
  }

  void stop() {
    _bleManager.stopScan();
  }

  void _handleScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
    print('results length: ${results.length}');

    for (ScanResult result in results) {
      print(result.device.id.toString());

      if (result.device.id.toString() == _beaconId) {
        double distance = DistanceComputation.calculateDistance(result.rssi, -50);
        String anchorId = result.device.name;
        AnchorDistance anchorDistance = _anchorDistances.firstWhere((ad) => ad.id == anchorId);
        anchorDistance.distance = distance;

        // print distance and rssi
        print('distance: $distance');
        print('rssi: ${result.rssi}');
      }
    }

    Vector3? position = calculatePosition();

    if (position != null) {
      _userPosition.setX(position.x);
      _userPosition.setY(position.y);
      _userPosition.setZ(position.z);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Vector3? calculatePosition() {
    List<AnchorDistance> filteredAnchors =
    _anchorDistances.where((ad) => ad.distance != 0).toList();

    if (filteredAnchors.length < 3) {
      return null;
    }

    HyperTrilateration trilateration = HyperTrilateration(filteredAnchors);

    trilateration.compute();

    double x = trilateration.getX();
    double y = trilateration.getY();
    double z = trilateration.getZ();

    return Vector3(x, y, z);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _bleManager.stopScan();
  }

  List<AnchorDistance> get anchorDistances => _anchorDistances;
}
```

Comment: bad state probably caused by the class name is same with another class from another package.

Comment: looks like your list was empty.

Comment: ```AnchorDistance anchorDistance = _anchorDistances.firstWhere((ad) => ad.id == anchorId);```
The error is due to this line. There's no element in _anchorDistances with ID equal to ancher ID.

Comment: @AnkeetKarki I had a feeling that line have an error but I am unable to go about fixing it. I tried doing orElse but it throws me an error saying that the return type isn't an 'AnchorDistance'

Comment: @Rahul which list are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

While using `firstWhere` in Flutter, if the list doesn't have element with the condition specified inside `firstWhere` then it'll throw `Bad State : no element` error. So, you need to check if there's element with specified condition in the list.
For this create a new file and paste the following block of code:

```
extension FirstWhereOrNull<T> on Iterable<T> {
  T? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(T) condition) {
    final data = this.where((condition)).toList();
    return data.isEmpty ? null : data[0];
  }
}
```

This will return the first item with the condition specified or else it'll return null.

Now in your code, replace the line with error which is

```
AnchorDistance anchorDistance = _anchorDistances.firstWhere((ad) => ad.id == anchorId);
anchorDistance.distance = distance;
```

with

```
AnchorDistance? anchorDistance = _anchorDistances.firstWhereOrNull((ad) => ad.id == anchorId);
if(anchorDistance != null){
    ancorDistance.distance = distance;
  }
```

This'll work. Use it as per your requirement.